# Nginx X-Accel-Mapping header for two locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Some context:

I want to be able to trigger file download from a Rails app, and make the files be downloaded by Nginx.

I can make that work for one folder, but not for two different folders.

I'm using something like the following:

```
# nginx config 

location /filestorage/ {
  internal;
  alias   /mnt/filestorage/;
}

proxy_set_header  X-Accel-Mapping       /mnt/filestorage/=/filestorage/;

# controller code (e.g. app/controllers/downloads_controller.rb)
send_file('/mnt/filestorage/my_file.zip')
```

I've tried something like the following to support another folder:

```
location /filestorage/ {
  internal;
  alias   /mnt/filestorage/;
}

location /filestorage2/ {
  internal;
  alias   /mnt/filestorage/;
}

proxy_set_header  X-Accel-Mapping "/mnt/filestorage/=/filestorage/ /mnt/filestorage2/=/filestorage2/";

# controller code (e.g. app/controllers/downloads_controller.rb)
send_file('/mnt/filestorage/my_file.zip')
send_file('/mnt/filestorage2/another_file.zip')
```

However, that doesn't work and makes none of the files in both folders available.

Is there a way to pass to locations to the X-Accel-Mapping header?

Answer (score 0):

Too late but a workarround might be like this.
(in application.rb or an initializer)

```
config.middleware.swap(
  ::Rack::Sendfile,
  ::Rack::Sendfile, 'X-Accel-Redirect',
  [['file_path', 'nginx_internal'],
   ['....','.....']]  

)
```